# Debian/Ubuntu - No network connection

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, ubuntu-12.04

I have a very weird situation on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Server. I can not access (ping) my gateway, although I believe my config is ok - I attach the outputs. Any hints where to look?
(I changed the beginning of the IP to something different, just obfuscation)
**ping 5.9.10.129**

```
PING 5.9.10.129 (5.9.10.129) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 5.9.10.129 (5.9.10.129) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 5.9.10.129 (5.9.10.129) icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 5.9.10.129 (5.9.10.129) icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
```

**uname -r**

3.2.0-29-generic

**ifconfig eth0**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3c:97:0e:0e:54:d7  
      inet addr:5.9.10.142  Bcast:5.9.10.159  Mask:255.255.255.224
      inet6 addr: fe80::8e70:5aff:feda:c4ac/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1216 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:490 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:107470 (107.4 KB)  TX bytes:34344 (34.3 KB)
      Interrupt:17 Memory:d2500000-d2520000
```

**ip route**

```
default via 5.9.10.129 dev eth0  metric 100
5.9.10.128/27 via 5.9.10.129 dev eth0 
5.9.10.128/27 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 5.9.10.142
```

route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         5.9.10.129      0.0.0.0         UG    1000      0        0 eth0
5.9.10.128      5.9.10.129      255.255.255.224 UG    0         0        0 eth0
5.9.10.128      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0         0        0 eth0
```

**iptables -L**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination       


Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source               destination
```

UPD: Eric, this is how routing information looks on a working server:

```
0.0.0.0         78.47.198.49    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
78.47.198.48    78.47.198.49    255.255.255.240 UG    0      0        0 eth0
78.47.198.48    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U     0      0        0 eth0
```

As I understand it, Hetzner tries to ensure security by this, so I can not take over an IP by changing my MAC. But this is another server, which has another netmask (255.255.255.240)

UPD2: BatchyX,
on the working server:

```
78.47.198.49 dev eth0  src 78.47.198.60 
    cache
```

on the broken:

```
5.9.10.129 dev eth0  src 5.9.10.142
    cache
```

Comment: 255.255.255.224 is a very strange netmask

Comment: why is 224 a strange mask?

Comment: 255.255.255.224 isn't a strange mask at all, it corresponds to a /27.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm affraid there is some problem with Hetzner IP class 5.9.x.x. We experience the same problems with our servers in this IP class. Some people are unable to connect and the traceroute show 'no route to host' at the beginning of traceroute (as if the local ISP would denied routing):

## ping 5.9.200.x

Destination Host Unreachable

EDIT: found in http://www.webhostingtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-1155588.html :

Quote: **"there are some ISP around (even an italian residential one) that appear to be filtering 5.0.0.0/8 ...
it's not an hetzner issue! it's an issue of your home ISP!"**

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd route seems to be an error : "5.9.10.129/27 via 5.9.10.129 dev eth0" You should not need any route as your server is in the 5.9.10.128/27 netwoork.

Comment: Sorry, this was my mistake, it should read 5.9.10.128. I just checked everything again and it should be the right output now. I checked on my other server, this kind of route is on all servers (but different IP)

Comment: Why would you pass all trafic to local subnet thru gateway?

Comment: Because this server is hosted, and this is the default route Hetzner suggests. Otherwise you do not have access to other machines.

Comment: No, Route #3 should be enough to access other machines on the same subnet, unless there are some really crappy and unknown reasons.

Comment: Dear Eric, it seems "crappy and unknown" as I have the "same" settings on my other (working) server. I updated the post so you may see the other (working conf).

Comment: @leviathanus: run `ip route get 5.9.10.129` on both machines and tell us the results. you will see that the bogus route is bogus.

Comment: BatchyX, I updated the topic.

Comment: @leviathanus: then there is a problem with 5.9.10.129, as it shouldn't send icmp errors in that case. maybe its configuration does not match ? but still, that routing table is still bogus, either it should be `5.9.10.128/27 dev eth0`, or it should be `5.9.10.129/32 dev eth0` but not a mix of both.